# Kotlin showed type mismatch in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-context

I have a fragment with RecyclerAdapter inside it. I want to initialize the adapter in the `onCreateView` method but it throws the error of `"Type mismatch. Required : Context , Found : FragmentActivity"` in this statement

I have no idea why the first one showed this error and the second one did not contains compile time error.

Error shown

```
recyclerView!!.adapter = RestaurantMenuAdapter(activity)
```

No Error shown

```
recyclerView!!.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
```

Fragment.kt

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_restaurant_menu, container, false)
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.restaurant_container)
    recyclerView!!.adapter = RestaurantMenuAdapter(activity)
    recyclerView!!.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
```

RecyclerAdapter.kt

```
class RestaurantMenuAdapter  (val context : Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val inflater = parent.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        return object : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_menu1, parent, false)) {

        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return 10
    }
}
```

Comment: why you pass context to your adapter? i think you do not need to pass it.

Comment: I may use context in the future. In fact, I used to pass Context as parameter in the adapter in java as the same way I did it in the above. In the past, I used to pass Fragment getActivity() as Context in the Adapter constructor as the parameter which accepted Context Type. I have no idea why this time did not work

Comment: @LongRanger Solved this yet?

Comment: Yes, at least I accepted to use activity.applicationContext to solve my problem. But I am still confusing with the activity in fragment

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Change this from :

```
recyclerView!!.adapter = RestaurantMenuAdapter(activity)
```

To :

```
recyclerView!!.adapter = RestaurantMenuAdapter(activity.applicationContext)
```

Comment: are you extending Fragment or FragmentActivity?

Comment: Yes, the Fragment extends to android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Comment: do this then class RestaurantMenuAdapter  (val context : Activity)

Comment: It seems this applicationContext works. But it showed I still need to add this activity!!.applicationContext before I passed to the adapter.

Comment: Do one thing change this - (val context : Context)  to-(val context : FragmentActivity) and do the same code below.

Answer (score 9):

```
recyclerView!!.adapter = RestaurantMenuAdapter(this)
```

To

```
recyclerView!!.adapter = RestaurantMenuAdapter(this.requireActivity())
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep the adapter as it and just use "activity!!" where you are initializing adapter.

```
recyclerView.adapter = RestaurantMenuAdapter(activity!!)
```

Your adapter will remain same.

```
class RestaurantMenuAdapter  (val context : Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    val inflater = parent.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
    return object : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_menu1, parent, false)) {

    }
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return 10
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change in Recycler Adapter
from Context to Activity.

```
class RestaurantMenuAdapter  (val context : Activity) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val inflater = parent.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        return object : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_menu1, parent, false)) {

        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return 10
    }
}
```